# Flutter wait for listen() function

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, flutter-getx, listen

I am trying to get a list of groups with this function:
I am using `GetX`, `RxDart`and `Streams`.

```dart
Rx<Stream<List<FrediUserGroup>>> groupsStream = Rx<Stream<List<FrediUserGroup>>>(Stream.value([]));
  
List<FrediUserGroup> get groupList {
    List<FrediUserGroup> groups = [];
    groupsStream.value.listen((event) {
      groups = event;
      //print(groups) => [...,...,...,] prints list of complete groups
    });
    //always returns [];
    return groups;
  }
```

How can I wait for the listening to finish before returning the value?

OR
How can I correctly return the listener function and return event inside of it (gives me an error: ***A value of type 'StreamSubscription<List<FrediUserGroup>>' can't be returned from the function 'groupList' because it has a return type of 'List<FrediUserGroup>'***.

Comment: your getter cannot return a list from an async stream - it has to return `Future` at least - for example by using `Stream.first` / `Stream.tolist` / `Completer`

Comment: so I will always have to use `future builder` / `stream builder` to inject that into my widgets? there is no other way? @pskink

Comment: You can use many other ways but what's wrong with the two you mentioned? they are designed for cases like yours